# Passing data to custom console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a little project and been trying to make my own debug console kinda thing, something that i can customize to what i need instead of using firebug.. so far i've got the two parts i need working but not togehter. I have a script that is going to report what the mouse enters and clicks on, it workded printing directly to the window DIV i have set up,, then yesterday ran across a JQuery console which i really liked, i cut out everything i didn't need and it works fine within its self, but not sure how to pass the data from my other method to that one,, i compiled the basic stuff to try to get it working... its probably something simple as ussual with me LOL and i could be confusing myself and making it harder then it needs to be

if anyone could help out that would be great

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thawizanator/KfGeK/14/)

Comment: What's wrong with firebug and/or chrome-dev tools?

Comment: i haven't used them enough to learn how to set it to show only what i need in errors, and user actions etc.. with this i'd be able to just throw it on the page that i'm working on most of all helping me learn and understand the scripting

Comment: surprise - you can redefine console.log()

`console.log=function(d) {alert(d)}`

Comment: Please post code relevant to your question, not just a dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after having a day off from work to sit down and actually mess with it for a while, reading Trip's comment LOL i decided to just go through the thing and clean it up as if it was working and took out a couple dozen un-needed functions and wrapped the main guts i was needing into one function that contained everything and made sure i wasn't using multiple variables to avoid conflict and some tweaking i got it to work.. so my conclusion from it there was to many functions leftover after i was deleting the stuff i didn't need. so heres the working code,, just incase someone is searching for something like this

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqYac/73/)

big thanks to Trip for point out all the Methods being used

```
    function clock(){
    var dayarray        = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
    var montharray        = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
    var suffix             = "AM";    

    var currentTime    = new Date();
    var hours         = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes     = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var mydate        = new Date();
    var year        = mydate.getFullYear();
    var day            = mydate.getDay();
    var month        = mydate.getMonth();
    var daym        = mydate.getDate();

    if(hours >= 12){
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if(hours == 0){
        hours = 12;
    }
    if(minutes < 10){
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    if(daym<10){
        daym="0"+daym
    }

    //alert(hours);
    return [hours, minutes, suffix, month, day, year, dayarray, montharray];
}
$('#consolex').click(function() { loadConsole(); });
var xD;

function loadConsole(){
if (document.forms[0].console.checked) {
        // if CHECKED than LOAD Console
            if (window.twd_console) {
                window.twd_console.toggle();
            } else {
                function init($) {
                    function HistoryManager() {
                        this.curr = -1;
                        this.entries = [];
                    };
                    HistoryManager.prototype = {
                        push: function(item) {
                            if (this.entries.length && this.entries[0] == item) return;
                            if (item.match(/^\s*$/)) return;
                            this.entries.unshift(item);
                            this.curr = -1;
                        },
                        scroll: function(direction) {
                            var moveTo = this.curr + (direction == 'prev' ? 1 : -1);
                            if (moveTo >= 0 && moveTo < this.entries.length) {
                                this.curr = moveTo;
                                return this.entries[this.curr];
                            } else if (moveTo == -1) {
                                this.curr = moveTo;
                                return '';
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    var toolbar = 'hello';
                    var context = {},
                        history = new HistoryManager(),
                        $drag = $('<div/>').css({
                            backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
                            border: '1px solid #a0a0a0',
                            fontSize: '11px',
                            fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                            lineHeight: 1,
                            padding: '5px',
                            marginBottom: '7px',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            textAlign: 'right'
                        }).html(toolbar),
                        $log = $('<div/>').css({
                            fontSize: '11px',
                            fontFamily: 'monospace',
                            color: 'white',
                            marginBottom: '7px',
                            height: '155px',
                            overflow: 'auto',
                            border: '1px solid #a0a0a0',
                            padding: '5px',
                            textAlign: 'left'
                        }),
                        $dummy = $('<div/>');

                    xD = function append(text, act, tag, id, color) {
                        var aX = ' »    ', // Bullet
                        bX = '['+ clock()[0]+':'+clock()[1]+':'+clock()[2]+']  ', // Timestamp
                        cX = '  ERROR  ', //ERROR
                        dX = '  Location  ', //Location of ERROR
                        eX = '  ID Location  ', //ID Location
                        fX = '  Cause  '; //Cause of ERROR
                        $log.append($('<div/>').css({
                            'color': color || 'black',
                            margin: 0,
                            padding: 0
                        }).text(aX).append(bX).append(text).append(act).append(tag).append(id));
                        $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight;
                    };

                    $(document).mousemove(function(evt) {
                        if (dragging) $container.css({
                            left: evt.pageX - dragging[0],
                            top: evt.pageY - dragging[1]
                        });
                    });

                    var pos = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';

                    var $container = $('<div/>').css({
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        padding: '7px',
                        position: pos,
                        opacity: 0.9,
                        top: '10px',
                        right: '10px',
                        width: '550px',
                        height: '200px',
                        border: '1px solid #000',
                        zIndex: 99999
                    }).appendTo(document.body);

                    $container.append($drag).append($log);

                    //xD('jQuery initialised!', 'green');
                    //xD('(using jQuery version ' + $.fn.jquery + ')');
                    //xD('jQuery initialised!', 'green');
                    //xD('(using jQuery version ' + $.fn.jquery + ')');
                    //xD('jQuery initialised!', 'green');
                    //xD('(using jQuery version ' + $.fn.jquery + ')');
                    //xD('jQuery initialised!', 'green');
                    //xD('(using jQuery version ' + $.fn.jquery + ')');

                    window.twd_console = $container;

                };

                if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined' || !jQuery.fn.jquery.match(/^1\.7/)) {
                    var e = document.createElement('script'),
                        jq = null;
                    e.onload = function() {
                        jq = jQuery;
                        jQuery.noConflict(true);
                        init(jq);
                    };
                    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js');
                    document.body.appendChild(e);
                } else {
                    init(jQuery);
                }
            }
    } else if (!document.forms[0].console.checked) {
        window.twd_console.hide();
    }    
    mouse(true);
}
        function mouse(bol){
            var d = $("*", document.body);

            if(bol){              
                // Cancel mousedown.
                d.mousedown(function(event) {
                    var x = $(this).get(0),
                    y = x.tagName,
                    z = x.id;
                    switch (event.which) {
                        case 1:
                            //alert('Left mouse button click: ' + x.tagName);

                            xD(x.tagName, '  Left mouse button  ','  '+ x.tagName+'  ','  '+ x.id+'  ', 'purple');
                            //xD(x.id, 'red');
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            //alert('Middle mouse button click: ' + x.tagName);
                            xD(x.tagName, '  Centermouse button  ', x.tagName, x.id, 'purple');
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //alert('Right mouse button click: ' + x.tagName);
                            xD(x.tagName, '  Right mouse button  ', x.tagName, x.id, 'purple');
                            return null;
                            break;
                        default:
                            xD(x.tagName, '  mouse UNKNOWN  ', x.tagName, x.id, 'purple');
                    }
                });
                // Transfer focus, if already open.
                d.mouseenter(function(event) {
                    var x = $(this).get(0),
                    y = x.tagName,
                    z = x.id;
                   // $('#window').append('mouse entered' + x.tagName + '<br />');
                    try{
                        xD(y, '  Mouse Entered  ', y, z, 'blue');
                    //xD(y, 'blue');
                    }catch(err){
                        alert(err);
                }
                });            
            }
        };
```